# What is the difference between char * ptr = ""; char * ptr = NULL and char * ptr = malloc(1)?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am currently working on an Arduino platform and I am trying to get rid of all Strings through char [] and pointers in order to avoid problems with the memory of my Arduino nano. The following code was being used to generate a string and pass to a function which expects a char *:

```
char * ptr = "";
strcpy(ptr, "AT+CWJAP=\"");
strcat(ptr, wifi_ssid);
strcat(ptr,"\",\"");
strcat(ptr,WIFI_PASS);
strcat(ptr,"\"");
Serial.println(ptr);
addToPipe(ptr);
```

where:

```
void ESP8266::addToPipe(char  * cmd) {
  for(pipeSlot = 0; pipeSlot < PIPEMAXSIZE; pipeSlot++) {
    if(isCharArrayEmpty(pipe[pipeSlot])){
      Serial.print("Slot is Empty. New data:");
      Serial.println(cmd);
      pipe[pipeSlot] = cmd;
      pipeSlot = PIPEMAXSIZE; //for breaking loop
    } else {
      Serial.print("Slot is Full with:");
      Serial.println(pipe[pipeSlot]);
    }
  }
  printPipe();
}
```

but for some non-apparent reason the pointer ptr was being printed in the Serial port continuously. However, by changing the above string generation with the following:

```
char * ptr = malloc(1);
strcpy(ptr, "AT+CWJAP=\"");
strcat(ptr, wifi_ssid);
strcat(ptr,"\",\"");
strcat(ptr,WIFI_PASS);
strcat(ptr,"\"");
Serial.println(ptr);
addToPipe(ptr);
```

seems to get rid of the problem. The question is, what is the difference between:

```
1. char * ptr = "";
2. char * ptr = malloc(1);
3. char * ptr = NULL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Undefined behavior, undefined behavior, undefined behavior... Try learning C from scratch.

Comment: The size you pass to [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) is the size in bytes. The string you create will not fit in a single byte. And considering that you program for an Arduino, it's really programmed in C++, and have a nice dynamic [`String` class](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) that you should learn to use. Use the library that is available to you, it will work much better in the long run than your own home-grown dynamic allocation.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Thanks for the heads up. I fixed the post.

Comment: The **first** and **foremost** mistake in your question is that you're asking about C, yet **your code is C++**.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have a version of this code using the String objects only. But since I read in the forums that it can suffer from lack of memory, I am replacing them with pointers and char arrays.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The tag was accidently added. Fixed now.

Comment: So instead of using the dynamic allocation of the `String` class (which is correct and working) you use your own dynamic allocation (which turns out to not be working)? I'd say go with the `String` object, especially as it will make many operations much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
char * ptr = malloc(1);
```

You're only allocating enough space for a single byte.  When you then try to `strcat` or `strcpy` anything to it, you're writing past the bounds of allocated memory.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Assigning `""` to `ptr` also won't work because it now points to a (empty) string literal and string literals can't be modified.  Assigning `NULL` also won't work because it's undefined behavior to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

You need to allocate enough space to hold the entire string plus the terminating null byte:

```
char *ptr = malloc(10 + strlen(wifi_ssid) + 3 + strlen(WIFI_PASS) + 1 + 1);
strcpy(ptr, "AT+CWJAP=\"");
strcat(ptr, wifi_ssid);
strcat(ptr,"\",\"");
strcat(ptr,WIFI_PASS);
strcat(ptr,"\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for the illustrative example. I thought that  the strcpy already returned a pointer to new allocated memory and the poiner *ptr was "re-pointed" to it, therefore it was not necessary to allocated the entire required memory in the original pointer. Thank you ver much.

Comment: @vtolentino Good one... The strcpy is not allocating/reallocating anything. It's your responsibility to provide enough space to work with.